# How to recover a file history in git

Tags: eclipse, git, history

After installing Android tools in my working Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 copy, something went really wrong to the point where I was forced to delete Eclipse and reinstall it. My workspace was compromised and even my git repository was damaged.

I have files that I committed at least once a day for the past three weeks and they were reverted to their first version. This is only one example of the disaster, other files have a damaged history too, this specific case is illustrated below

```
git log -p --follow PartyEvaluationModels/Resources/Rules/Person.d2wmodel

commit d48d3c9b7dbb8769278a70f1400947d87e7f0d6d
Author: Ângelo Andrade Cirino <>
Date:   Tue May 13 15:11:20 2014 -0300

    Tentativa de implementação com ERPartials e adição de arquivos de regras
    para todas as entidades até agora definidas.

diff --git a/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel b/PartyEvaluationModels/Resources/Rules/Person.d2wmodel
similarity index 100%
copy from PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel
copy to PartyEvaluationModels/Resources/Rules/Person.d2wmodel

commit 4d51eb3fa72fee750ba4b0a7e8c53216a9ea0b25
Author: Ângelo Andrade Cirino <>
Date:   Thu May 8 23:17:01 2014 -0300

    Funcionalidades para omitir atributos de entidades e abas de telas de
    edição de entidades foram implementados com sucesso.

diff --git a/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel b/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel
index b6b1df4..7793fda 100644
--- a/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel
+++ b/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 {
-    rules = (
-    );
-}
+  "rules" = (
+  ); 
+}
\ No newline at end of file

commit df14fc9d4dc2f811307b704f85d59b8cc8b0b9a7
Author: Ângelo Andrade Cirino <>
Date:   Sun Mar 30 23:44:27 2014 -0300

    Inserção do projeto Party

diff --git a/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel b/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b6b1df4
--- /dev/null
+++ b/PartyEvaluation/Resources/d2w.d2wmodel
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+{
+    rules = (
+    );
+}
```

As I said, this file was committed almost daily and now all its history is lost locally and on GitHub too. Since my local copy and GitHub lost its history I guess I lost three weeks of work on several files.

I will be very grateful if someone helps me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how GitHub's history was lost too; that shouldn't be possible unless you used `push --force`.  Is it possible you did all this work on another branch?

Assuming not...

`git reflog` will show you old "incarnations" of HEAD; it remembers what a branch looked like before something rewrote history, and will usually have a hash for whatever you've lost.

Or to do the same thing across all branches, `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline --all`.

Once you've found your commits, checkout master, and `git reset --hard SHA` to forcefully point that branch at the correct hash.  But make sure you have the right commit or you'll just make this worse.  :)

Comment: Hi, thanx for your help. I own this repo and there is no other branch. The commits I need to revert to are simply gone, can't be found. Anyway, the specific file commits seem to have been randomly removed from the history, since I can see all my history, but specific files commit history has been reset to random dates. Like the one example I posted.

Comment: wait, how did you lose weeks of work if you still have the full history?  can you add `git status` and a sample of `git log --all --graph --decorate --pretty='format:%h %n %s'` to your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `git revert commit_sha` 

If you do it this way, your history does not be overwritted and one commit per revert will be created

Otherwise, you can checkout the file with commit_sha and then commit the change. This way will create only one commit in your history

Comment: this does not appear to have anything to do with the question.  this is about lost commits, not errant commits.